# Solidity test: Contract calling another Contract and addresses are different

Tags: solidity, testrpc, addresses, testing

I have a wrapper contract that instantiates and calls another contract, and my test cases say the owners (msg.sender)s don't match. Why?

**contract A**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract A {

    function A() {
    }

    function createB(string name) {
        return new B(msg.sender, name);
    }
}
```

**contract B**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract B {
    address owner
    string public name;

    function B(address _owner, string _name) {
        owner = _owner;
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

**test case**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/B.sol";

contract TestB {
    B testB;
    A testA;

    function beforeEach() {
        A = A(DeployedAddresses.A());
        B = testA.createB("test");
    }

    function testOwnerIsSet() {
        Assert.equal(address(A), address(B), "Owner's address does not match");
    }
}
```

**Test Results**

```
 1) TestB testOwnerIsSet:
     Error: Owner's address does not match
      at /Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:214233:17
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at processResult (/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:214231:19)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

**EDIT**

I have added the `address public owner` to `contract A`. And made `owner` public in `contract B`.

And now my TestB contract looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/B.sol";

contract TestB {
    B testB;
    A testA;

    function beforeEach() {
        A = A(DeployedAddresses.A());
        B = testA.createB("test");
    }

    function testOwnerIsSet() {
        address aOwner = A.owner();
        address bOwner = B.owner();
        Assert.equal(aOwner, bOwner, "Owner's address does not match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note that if you call `createB` like previously:

```
function createB(string name) public returns (address) {
  return new B(name)
}
```

Inside B constructor you will have `msg.sender = address(A)`, because
A is creating B.

To make it work as intended you have to send the owner to B constructor like this:

Contract A.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

import "./B.sol";

contract A {
    address public owner;
    function A() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createB(string name) public returns (address) {
        return new B(owner, name);
    }
}
```

Contract B.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract B {
    address public owner;
    string public name;
    function B(address _owner, string _name) {
        owner = _owner;
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Contract TestB.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/A.sol";
import "../contracts/B.sol";

contract TestB {
  B testB;
  A testA;

  function beforeEach() {
    testA = A(DeployedAddresses.A());
    testB = B(testA.createB("test"));
  }

  function testIsOwnerIsSet() {
    address aOwner = testA.owner();
    address bOwner = testB.owner();
    Assert.equal(aOwner, bOwner, "Owner's address does not match");
  }
}
```

---

Before Edit

But you never call owner you are comparing the addresses of contract A, and contract B. You should compare

```
Assert.equal(address(A), address(B.owner), "Owner's address does not match")
```

But make sure owner is public in contract B.

Comment: I will try this, but I believe I already have tried this. Setting B's owner field to public and trying the assert. Will get back to you.

Comment: Sending in the `owner` when creating contract B worked! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Ismael is right. Your contracts need `public` owner variables so you can do something like:

```
    A a = A(<address where A is deployed);
    address AOwner = a.owner();
...
    assert(AOwner,BOwner,"Owner's should both be the same");
```

I fiddled with it a little and came up with this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract A {

    address public owner; // add this

    function A() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createB(string name) returns(address deployed) {
        return new B(msg.sender, name);
    }
}

pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract B {

    address public owner;
    string public name;

    function B(address _owner, string _name) {
        owner = _owner;
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just tried this but still getting a failing test. Please see my `edited` code in OP. Should I not be doing the `beforeEach()` call? Could that cause some issues with my addresses?